# Is it okay to give a slash after sources.list entry?

Tags: apt, configuration

In my sources.list file I fount that the entries like( I'm using Debian ):

`deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main`

I wonder is it completely okay to have a slash after the website name :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
```

Is there any difference between the two ?

Answer (score 7):

It's not stated explicitly in the `sources.list` manpage, but yes, it's OK to have a `/` after the URI. In fact, `apt`, when reading the `sources.list` files, [adds the trailing `/` if not present](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/2.5.0/apt-pkg/sourcelist.cc#L90-92):

```
   // Make sure that the URI is / postfixed
   if (URI.back() != '/')
      URI.push_back('/');
```

The presence or absence of trailing `/` matters for the `suite` (earlier called `distribution`) component (`bullseye` in your example), and this is documented in [the `sources.list` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/apt/sources.list.5.en.html#THE_DEB_AND_DEB-SRC_TYPES:_GENERAL_FORMAT):

> suite can specify an exact path, in which case the components must be
> omitted and suite must end with a slash (/). This is useful for the
> case when only a particular sub-directory of the archive denoted by
> the URI is of interest. If suite does not specify an exact path, at
> least one component must be present.